# approximate bijective function such that the inverses are bijective and "easily" computable

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory

I have a infinitely differentiable, bijective function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, and I would like to approximate this function by a series of other functions $T_i$ (think Taylor) – with the conditions that

- all the approximants are also bijective and
- its inverse must be representable by elementary functions (addition, multiplication, exponentation, $\exp$, $\log$, $\sin$ etc.).

Taylor polynomials do *not* fit this bill since, as polynomials, root finding is not elementary.

Any hints here? Links to articles could suffice.

Comment: I do not understand why Taylor polynomials do not fit. The inverse of a polynomial is an elementary function.

Comment: Only up to degree 4. By the Abel–Ruffini theorem, there is no algebraic solution to general polynomials equations of degree 5 or higher.

Comment: As crude as it is, do you consider piecewise linear functions elementary?

Comment: @orlp A good suggestion. For the actual application I'm working towards (the same thing in higher dimensions) piecewise linear functions probably aren't _that_ useful though. Given a point in a discretized $n$D space, it'll be computationally expensive to find which segment (/simplex) the point is in. Nevertheless: A good suggestion.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Well, you can setup piecewise linear functions such that the _output_ domain is divided into equidistant sections, which makes the inverse trivial to compute (at the cost of forward computation time). It depends on whether you mostly do inverses or forward invocations.

Comment: I think we need more information about the specific functions you have in mind. If your perspective is practical rather than stricty theoretical, then I also think you need to reconsider your demands. The floating point realization of the function $f(x) = 1 - x$ is not bijective, as $1-x$ is rounded to $1$ all sufficiently small floating point numbers $x>0$. One way or another, the computer realization of your approximations can be reduced to a finite number of elementary arithmetic operations and table lookups.